# ITMS-9000 Error - Bundle is invalid. + Unable to authenticate the package

Tags: ios7, xcode5, bundle, app-store-connect

I'm not able to upload my binary.
I developed with XCode 5.1 beta for iOS 7.0+. So I can't understand this error message.
Does anyone has an idea what to do now?

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Don't upload your binary with the beta versions.
With XCode 5.0.2 it worked fine!